# CPU Usage Incorrect in sys.dm_os_ring_buffers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, ubuntu, dmv, sp-blitz

I'm running a cloud VPS with a SQL Server instance. Because it's for personal use, I'm using express edition (I can't use developer edition because I *technically* have production apps running on it and there's no way I could afford Standard+).

I'm trying to get baseline captures going using [Brent Ozar's tutorial](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/02/video-how-to-capture-baselines-with-sp_blitzfirst/) using `sp_BlitzFirst`. The problem I'm running into is that `ProcessUtilization` in `sys.dm_os_ring_buffers` always comes out as `100`, no matter what the actual CPU usage is at the time.

### VM Info

> **@@version:** Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU15) (KB4498951) - 14.0.3162.1 (X64)   May 15 2019 19:14:30    Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation    Express Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu
>   18.04.2 LTS)

**Host:** 1 & 1 Ionos VPS

**lscpu output**

> ```
> Architecture:        x86_64
> CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
> Byte Order:          Little Endian
> CPU(s):              2
> On-line CPU(s) list: 0,1
> Thread(s) per core:  1
> Core(s) per socket:  1
> Socket(s):           2
> NUMA node(s):        1
> Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
> CPU family:          6
> Model:               63
> Model name:          Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 5120 CPU @ 2.20GHz
> Stepping:            0
> CPU MHz:             2194.844
> BogoMIPS:            4389.68
> Hypervisor vendor:   VMware
> Virtualization type: full
> L1d cache:           32K
> L1i cache:           32K
> L2 cache:            1024K
> L3 cache:            19712K
> NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0,1
> Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc cpuid pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm cpuid_fault invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 invpcid xsaveopt arat flush_l1d arch_capabilities
> ```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Microsoft says](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SQL-Server/SQL-Server-CPU-usage-available-in-sys-dm-os-ring-buffers-DMV/ba-p/825361) that DMV (ring buffers) doesn't work on SQL Server 2017, only 2019:

> Sys.dm_os_ring_buffers DMV has been a key DMV used for monitoring SQL
>   Server by built-in tools as well as third party monitoring utilities.
>   When SQL Server 2017 was released on Linux, unfortunately this DMV did
>   not return correct CPU usage information by SQL Server process. SQL
>   Server team is glad to announce that the starting with SQL Server 2019
>   release candidate, the sys.dm_os_ring_buffers DMV returns SQL CPU
>   utilization correctly.

Comment: I'm using SQL 2019 CU-20 on Windows 2022 (VM) and I have the opposite problem. dm_os_ring_buffers always returns 0 for ProcessUtilization. I have not confirmed it yet, but I think the problem for me is that I'm running SQL on a VM.